# Replacement by matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need to match numbers followed by a unit and replace them with digits+underscore+unit using Javascript.

I came out with this code, which does not produce the result I am seeking to achieve.

```
var x = myFunction("I have 3 billion dollars");

function myFunction(text) {
return  text.replace(/(\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?) (\bmillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bmillions\b|\bbillions\b|\btrillion\b|\btrillions\b|\bmeter\b|\bmeters\b|\bmile\b|\bmiles\b|\%)/gi, function (match) {
          return "<span class='highlighted'>" + match[1] + "_" + match[2] + "</span>";
    });
 }
```

The above code should return "I have 3_billion dollars" (but it returns _b as far as the substitution is concerned). As I am a newbe with Java, any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit**
Already many useful hints! Here some more imputs examples:

```
the street is 4.5 miles long
the budget was 430.000 dollars
```

Comment: How much variation is there to the input string? can you provide more samples or would the always be something similar to _string_ **number** _**space**_ _**unit**_ _string_?

Comment: `match` in `function (match)`  is the whole matched string. You could make it with `function (match, group1, group2)` and use `group1` and `group2` instead of `match[1]` and `match[2]`, but you really do not need the anonymous method, use `text.replace(your_regex, "<span class='highlighted'>$1_$2</span>")`

Comment: Hi Randy, the input is basically running text which may contain numbers (any format) and a set of unit of measurement. In this case, I was more interested in the error of my Javascrit and less in the regex (which I may need to adapt). The error being that "match" was not an array but a string, as pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.replace` with your original expression, if it would work:

```js
const regex = /(\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?) (\bmillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bmillions\b|\bbillions\b|\btrillion\b|\btrillions\b|\bmeter\b|\bmeters\b|\bmile\b|\bmiles\b|\%)/gm;
const str = `3 billion
3 million`;
const subst = `<span class='highlighted'>" $1_$2 "</span>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Also, we can slightly simplify our expression:

```
(\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?) (\bmillions?\b|\bbillions?\b|\btrillions?\b|\bmeters?\b|\bmiles?\b|\%)
```

```js
const regex = /(\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?) (\bmillions?\b|\bbillions?\b|\btrillions?\b|\bmeters?\b|\bmiles?\b|\%)/gm;
const str = `3 billion
3 million
3 %
2 meters`;
const subst = `<span class='highlighted'>" $1_$2 "</span>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2w8EI/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/p2w8EI/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: All the answers were good, but I choose this one because very complete and informative.

Answer (score 2):

Simple more clearer example for you

```js
let regex = /\d+ (million|billion|millions|billions|trillion|trillions|meter|meters|mile|miles)/g

let match = "I have 3 billion dollars".match(regex)
let replace = match.map(x => x.split(" ").join("_"))

console.log(replace)
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` is not an array its a string. You could `split` it by `' '` join by `_`

```js
var x = myFunction("I have 3 billion dollars");

function myFunction(text) {
return  text.replace(/(\d+\.?(?:\d{1,2})?) (\bmillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bbillion\b|\bmillions\b|\bbillions\b|\btrillion\b|\btrillions\b|\bmeter\b|\bmeters\b|\bmile\b|\bmiles\b|\%)/gi, function (match) {
          console.log(match)
          return "<span class='highlighted'>" +match.split(' ').join('_')+ "</span>";
    });
 }
console.log(x)
```